# Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting ')'

Tags: php

Код:

```
$link = strtr($link, array('http://' => '', ':' => '', '}' => '', '"' => '', '{' => '', "(" => "", ")" => "", '&' => '', '$' => '', '!' => '', '#' => '', '№' => '', ';' => '', '%' => '', '^' => '', '?' => '', '*' => '', '=' => '', '+' => '[' => '', ']' => '', '/' => '', '>' => '', '<' => '', ',' => '', '|' => '', "'" => ""));
```

Ошибка:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting ')'
```

Вопрос:

Как исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 '+' => '[' => '',
```

Внимание удели этому кусочку, ведь ошибка явно написана

```
T_DOUBLE_ARROW
```

такие глупые ошибки, складывается впечатление что новички пишут скрипты в обычном блокноте.

Скачайте себе программу чтобы хоть код подсвечивала, ну и глазами ошибки некоторые явно же видно.

Comment: Да сам вижу что ошибки совсем простые, утомление, видимо... Как-никак уже скоро час ночи. Спасибо за помощь.