# Ошибка - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: php

Ребята подскажите в чем может быть ошибка ?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Код:

```
<?php 
    $leftMenu = array (  
      ('link' => 'Домой', 'href' => 'index.php'),     
      ('link' => 'О нас', 'href' => 'about.php'),      
      ('link' => 'Контакты', 'href' => 'contact.php'),    
      ('link' => 'Таблица умножения', 'href' => 'table.php'),     
      ('link' => 'Калькулятор', 'href' => 'calc.php')
      ); 
    ?>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/75318/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-double-arrow-expecting второе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/363091/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-syntax-error-unexpected-t-double-arrow

Answer (score 0):

Один раз ты написал `array`, а внутри массива кто будет писать это слово для объявления других массивов, Пушкин?

```
$leftMenu = array (  
     array ('link' => 'Домой', 'href' => 'index.php'),     
     array ('link' => 'О нас', 'href' => 'about.php'),      
     array ('link' => 'Контакты', 'href' => 'contact.php'),    
     array ('link' => 'Таблица умножения', 'href' => 'table.php'),     
     array ('link' => 'Калькулятор', 'href' => 'calc.php')
);
```

Comment: Бр-р, есть же квадратные скобки, зачем этот ископаемый синтаксис...

Comment: @Squidward вопрос же не об этом, хотя я порывался дополнить о "квадратиках", но что-то воздержался........ и сразу мне вспомнился случай, как меня один человек минусил за то, что я в ответах массивы через квадратные скобки писал :D